# Custom header for mod_deflate

Tags: apache, mod-deflate

Some mobile operators(rays of hate) turns of compression (remove header `Accept-Enconding`) when using internet.

Have the opportunity to respond `mod_deflate` to custom header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with mod_filter. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_filter.html for the Apache 2.4 version of the documentation, but this is available since Apache 2.1

You'll need to use the FilterProvider directive and an expression based on the custom header you want to pass.

I presume you have an iOS or Android app which can set the custom header? Alternatively, you can also set a custom header using JavaScript and XMLHTTPRequest.